# SnowFlake Diagram and Many to Many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, data-warehouse

I have a snowflake diagram with:

```
Fact: 
id_movie
id_user
rating

Dim Users:
id_user
...


Dim Movies:
id_movie
...
```

In my ERD, I also have a table Category, that has a many to many relationship with the movies like this:

```
Dim_Category:
id_category
...

Map_Category_Movie:
id_movie
id_category
relevance
```

I am trying to find an efficient way to model this in a snowflace/star schema. My issues:

- I could just add these two tables into the snowflake diagram, but this would feel wrong as I usually only use tables that are aggregates of the subtables on the outer fringes of this diagram.
- I could create another fact table for the relevance, but as I want to ultimately report on the correlation of relevance of users to their behaviour in rating in movie, I'd need to use both fact tables, which to me is an incorrect approach.

Any guidance here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is huge chance that you have already answered to yourself and welcome to hell.
First, quotation from http://www.information-management.com/ would be interested to you:

> The snowflake structure will reduce batch updates to dimensions. Though always said to be slower than a star, some tests have revealed no difference in performance between flattened and snowflaked dimensions. In fact in some cases, the snowflake provides superior performance, such as when a wide dimension (i.e., customer) is segmented into a snowflake.

So, using a bridge table is not going to cause significant loss of performance. I prefer snowflake in good percent of cases because sometimes is really easier to manage your data mart and hardware/size of data gives you an opportunity to do it.

My friendly advise is to create bridge table (movie_ID, category_ID, relevance) and go on.

If you have **fixed** and small list of categories, create table with predefined categories:

```
dim_movies
----------
movies_id
category1_relavance
category2_relavance
category3_relavance
```

Up to ten is perhaps ok, especially if you work for company you're creating dwh, not just consulting it (you can administer).

Once, we have tried to create a masterpiece of data warehouse, where was a similar example like yours. Payment deal was based on performance (data was over 2TB per fact table) so we decided to give shot to create star-schema.

We created dimension like I described above and every time when no. of distinct categories grows etl added new field in table.
ETL process also had to dynamically recreate the cube. 
It took a lot of pain but performance was as I remember 13% better than snow-flake.

Also, during the most exhaustively project, where I believe that 10y.o kid would designed DB better, we had to connect exact 5 categories per item. Each category points to one of 20+ possible tables. It could be joined ONLY through theirs software based on some rules. It was some kind of 1...5: Many relationship (it doesn't exists!?!)

```
pk     code_conto     cat1    cat2    cat3    cat4    cat5
----------------------------------------------------------
1      123            17      NULL    5467    12      NULL
2      124            67      1098    NULL    1423    AK12
3      123            NULL    NULL    NULL    13      23
```

Code was like this:

```
If (code_conto == 123)
{
    Category1_join_set = 'SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM cat_customers'; //NOTE THIS
    Category2_join_set = 'SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM cat_products';
    Category3_join_set = 'SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM cat_city';
    ...
    ...
}
    If (code_conto == 124)
{
    Category1_join_set = 'SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM cat_products'; //AND THIS
    Category2_join_set = 'SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM cat_origin';   //ON SAME FIELD
    Category3_join_set = 'SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM cat_blabla';   //DIFFERENT JOIN TABLE
    ...
    ...
}
```

All hard-coded. So we hard coded our queries with over 100 times repeating WHEN in CASE Statement. Guess what? ERP provider 'improved' his software and created mapping table where was 'C' if statements based on code_conto key.
We took more than 3 weeks to provide a good and secure ETL job (with SQLs, external tools).

I didn't wrote all this for nothing. I wanted to convince you and others that using bridge table in many to many relationships is probably the best practice in 97% percents.

However, there are five design solutions to M:M relationship possible:

1. Array or series (I don't want to even try it)
2. Bridge table
3. Groupings
4. Fixed levels
5. Dynamically created fixed levels

Hope I didn't confused you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up with a bridge table - from a sonwflake perspective I now have 2 fact tables sharing 2 of 3 dimension tables each. it's rare that I need to know the rating and category for the same item. I have however a much larger tag table and may consider storing these differently.