# Another snowflake schema with many-to-many dimension

Tags: many-to-many, dimensional-modeling, snowflake-schema

So there's already a question about [SnowFlake Diagram and Many to Many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344169/snowflake-diagram-and-many-to-many-relationship), but mine was a little bit different. Take a look at this schema.

[draw.io](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lZvm2lVFRIiOaRqGNxJ1gLrLL7GrASGL/view?usp=sharing) (sorry I can't upload image to Imgur)

This is a simple star schema, I want to capture/retrieve some metric that is identifiable by a user and a team so the above schema makes sense. But there's a many-to-many relationship between `dim_user` and `dim_team` which of course everyone wants to avoid many-to-many relationships. A common approach is to create a bridge table between `dim_user` and `dim_team`. But this doesn't look like snowflake schema, the fact table is connected to 2 dimension table that are have relationships.

In my mind, I think this is fine but since what I can find about snowflake is only one of those 2 dimensions is connected to a fact table, I'm afraid this is a design leak. Any thought about this?

Answer (score 0):

Just merge the Team attributes into the User Dim.

You can still keep the Team Dim as it is, if you have fact tables that are at the Team, rather than User, grain.